# How to read the list of files in a directory on another drive in web app?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

Here is a part of a simple web page to show a selector list of the available log files on an attached drive:

```
 public void OnGet()
    {
        StringBuilder logContent = new StringBuilder();
        string[] files = null;
        string directory = @"Q:\logs";
        string reason = "Undefined";
        try
        {
            files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.csv");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            reason = ex.Message;
        }
        if (files != null && files.Length > 0)
        {
            logContent.Append(@"<select>");
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string aFile = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) + 1);
                logContent.Append("<option value=\"" + aFile + "\">" + aFile + "</option>");
            }
            logContent.Append(@"</select>");
...
  else
    {
        logContent.Append("<h3>An Exception occurred: " + reason + "</h3>");
    }

    Message = logContent.ToString();
}
```

When the page runs, I get the exception

> "Cannot find a part of the path Q:\logs.

The drive is there and if I do a `dir Q:\logs` in the command prompt from C drive it displays the contents.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What does this have to do with the tag *azure*? Are you running this in an Azure web application?

Comment: It's running on Azure.

Comment: In an Azure virtual machine, or as an Azure web application?

Comment: It is running on an Azure virtual machine as an Azure web application.

Comment: If it's running in an Azure VM, it's **not** an Azure web application. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using IIS? 
If so, then the user that is running the application (application pool in IIS) has to be you. Otherwise, you need to map the drive for that user, since it sounds like Q is a network mapped drive.

Comment: Am using IIS on Azure.  I am the user, and I deployed the web app on Azure.  What user would I map the drive for?  All users can see this drive.

Comment: Google 'App Pool Identity'. It is likely running under Local System, Local Service, or I_USR if not joined to domain.